# What's wrong with my Euler's problem10 code?

Tags: primes

It just doesn't give out the correct answer for some reason and for some reason it gives correct one with smaller input.

```
public class Problem10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumPrimeNumber(2000000));
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int prime){
        boolean isPrime = true;
        if(prime%2==0)
            return false;
        for(int i = 3;i<=Math.pow(prime, 0.5);i+=2){
            if(prime%i==0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
    public static int sumPrimeNumber(int max){
        int sum = 0;
        int prime = 3;
        while(prime < max){
            if(isPrime(prime)){
                sum += prime;
            }
            prime += 2;
        }
        return sum + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use some higher datatype than INT since you are dealing with larger numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out I should change sum to long. I though that it didn't overflow because it gives out a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

Your int (max 2 billion) is probably overflowing.
Change ints to longs.

```
public class Problem10 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sumPrimeNumber(2000000));
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(long prime){
        boolean isPrime = true;
        if(prime%2==0)
            return false;
        for(int i = 3;i<=Math.pow(prime, 0.5);i+=2){
            if(prime%i==0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
    public static int sumPrimeNumber(long max){
        long sum = 0;
        int prime = 3;
        while(prime < max){
            if(isPrime(prime)){
                sum += prime;
            }
            prime += 2;
        }
        return sum + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's just 2 million and it gives out the answer which is also an int

Comment: Don't you think there are at least 1000 numbers between 1.000.000 and 2.000.000 which are prime? The sum of them will surely overflow.

Comment: You need to change the return-type of `sumPrimeNumber` to `long` as well (I suggested an edit, but despite your "_Change ints to longs._" three reviewers felt "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post.").  With this additional fix, the code gives the right answer.  You probably also should incorporate [rossum's fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36200105/2096401) although it doesn't affect the answer since the OP's code starts from 3 and adds the 2 in explicitly in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your `isPrime()` function has an error.  It flags 2 as composite, returning false.

Change the initial `if` to:

```
if (prime % 2 == 0)
  return prime == 2;
```

which will return `true` for 2 and `false` for other even numbers.

Comment: Correct, but in this case it doesn't matter since the loop only considers primes from 3 onwards (2 is added-in in the return statement).

Comment: Best to rename your method from `isPrime()` to `isOddPrime()` to indicate what it does more clearly.  Either that or correct its operation for 2.  Currently it does not operate as would be expected from its name.